# Rolling upgrade from Apache Kafka (kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1) to Confluent Platform 4.0 issue

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

We are trying to perform the rolling upgrade from the Apache Kafka version **kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1** to the Kafka provided by **Confluent 4.0**, and we also want to retain current data.

These are steps we have performed:

1. Shutdown a Apache Kafka broker.
2. Copy the server.properties from current to new old to ensure it is matched.
3. Start new Kafka node from Confluent installation.

However, we are facing when new node trying to join the Kafka cluster as I could  not be able to fetch replica from other nodes in the Kafka cluster.

Error as below:

```
GC_USR-0 as the leader reported an error: UNKNOWN_SERVER_ERROR (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2017-12-21 02:51:33,869] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=0, fetcherId=0] Retrying leaderEpoch request for partition __consumer_offsets-48 as the leader reported an error: UNKNOWN_SERVER_ERROR (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2017-12-21 02:51:33,869] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=0, fetcherId=0] Retrying leaderEpoch request for partition DCN_USR_RETRY-0 as the leader reported an error: UNKNOWN_SERVER_ERROR (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2017-12-21 02:51:33,869] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=0, fetcherId=0] Retrying leaderEpoch request for partition __consumer_offsets-19 as the leader reported an error: UNKNOWN_SERVER_ERROR (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2017-12-21 02:51:33,869] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=0, fetcherId=0] Retrying leaderEpoch request for partition GC_ACCT-0 as the leader reported an error: UNKNOWN_SERVER_ERROR (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2017-12-21 02:51:33,869] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=0, fetcherId=0] Retrying leaderEpoch request for partition __consumer_offsets-11 as the leader reported an error: UNKNOWN_SERVER_ERROR (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2017-12-21 02:51:33,869] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=0, fetcherId=0] Retrying leaderEpoch request for partition DCN_ERROR_TEST-0 as the leader reported an error: UNKNOWN_SERVER_ERROR (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2017-12-21 02:51:33,869] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=0, fetcherId=0] Retrying leaderEpoch request for partition DCN_MONITOR-0 as the leader reported an error: UNKNOWN_SERVER_ERROR (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2017-12-21 02:51:33,869] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=0, fetcherId=0] Retrying leaderEpoch request for partition __consumer_offsets-13 as the leader reported an error: UNKNOWN_SERVER_ERROR (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2017-12-21 02:51:33,869] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=0, fetcherId=0] Retrying leaderEpoch request for partition Hello-Yoga-Test-0 as the leader reported an error: UNKNOWN_SERVER_ERROR (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2017-12-21 02:51:33,869] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=0, fetcherId=0] Retrying leaderEpoch request for partition DCN_COUNT_TOPIC-0 as the leader reported an error: UNKNOWN_SERVER_ERROR (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2017-12-21 02:51:33,869] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=0, fetcherId=0] Retrying leaderEpoch request for partition __consumer_offsets-2 as the leader reported an error: UNKNOWN_SERVER_ERROR (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2017-12-21 02:51:33,869] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=0, fetcherId=0] Retrying leaderEpoch request for partition __consumer_offsets-43 as the leader reported an error: UNKNOWN_SERVER_ERROR (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2017-12-21 02:51:33,869] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=0, fetcherId=0] Retrying leaderEpoch request for partition DCN_INFRA_ERROR-0 as the leader reported an error: UNKNOWN_SERVER_ERROR (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2017-12-21 02:51:33,869] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=0, fetcherId=0] Retrying leaderEpoch request for partition __consumer_offsets-6 as the leader reported an error: UNKNOWN_SERVER_ERROR (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2017-12-21 02:51:33,869] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=0, fetcherId=0] Retrying leaderEpoch request for partition GC_ACL-0 as the leader reported an error: UNKNOWN_SERVER_ERROR (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2017-12-21 02:51:33,869] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=0, fetcherId=0] Retrying leaderEpoch request for partition DCN_REQUEST_GROUPS_OWNERSHIP-0 as the leader reported an error: UNKNOWN_SERVER_ERROR (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2017-12-21 02:51:33,869] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=0, fetcherId=0] Retrying leaderEpoch request for partition __consumer_offsets-14 as the leader reported an error: UNKNOWN_SERVER_ERROR (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2017-12-21 02:51:33,869] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=0, fetcherId=0] Retrying leaderEpoch request for partition DCN_MAILBOX_OWNER-0 as the leader reported an error: UNKNOWN_SERVER_ERROR (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2017-12-21 02:51:33,869] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=0, fetcherId=0] Retrying leaderEpoch request for partition TASK_REGISTRY_TEST-0 as the leader reported an error: UNKNOWN_SERVER_ERROR (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2017-12-21 02:51:33,869] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=0, fetcherId=0] Retrying leaderEpoch request for partition uatTest1-0 as the leader reported an error: UNKNOWN_SERVER_ERROR (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2017-12-21 02:51:33,869] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=0, fetcherId=0] Retrying leaderEpoch request for partition DCN_CMDB_TEST-0 as the leader reported an error: UNKNOWN_SERVER_ERROR (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
```

We could clean all existing data and setup a brand new a Confluent Platform cluster, but we have been using the Apache Kafka in production already so we don't want to lose data.

Please anyone can advise ?

Answer (score 1):

I have found out the solution.
Following configurations need to be added to server.properties.

```
inter.broker.protocol.version=0.10.1.1
log.message.format.version=0.10.1.1
```

Comment: *Once the entire cluster is upgraded, bump the protocol version by editing `inter.broker.protocol.version` and setting it to `1.0`*... http://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation.html#upgrade